# Proof by induction that recursive function $\text{take}$ satisfies $\text{take}(n) = 100 - 2n$

Tags: induction, recursion

I'm sick and tired off posting threads about induction... I just can't seem to get it, I need someone to give me a detailed explanation and treat me like a 5 year old, literally. I'm wasting a lot of time trying to revise one topic, and getting nowhere... I just don't understand :O

Here's an attempt :

[image]

Base case
take(0) = 100 - (2*0) = 100
therefore it holds

Assume n=k holds
take(k) = 100-(2*k)

prove take(k+1) = 100-(2*k+1)

take(k+1) = take(k)100-2k+1
take(k+2) = ...

Comment: No, you need to prove that $\mathsf{take}(k+1) = 100-2(k+1)$.

Comment: This topic is so difficult.......

Comment: Just replace $k$ with $k+1$ and nothing else. But you have to be careful, because $2k$ becomes $2(k+1)$ and not $2k+1$. (You can put parentheses around $k$ before replacing it with $k+1$ if it helps.) So $\mathsf{take}(k) = 100-2k$ becomes $\mathsf{take}(k+1) = 100-2(k+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

PARENTHESIS!

You want to prove

> ${\rm take}(n)=100-2n$

for the special case when $n=k+1$. So, *substitute* $k+1$ in place of the $n$, but not only formally, it is a separate unit, needs parenthesis:

> ${\rm take}(k+1)=100-2(k+1)$

Then open the parenthesis, so what you have to prove is

> ${\rm take}(k+1)=100-2k-2$

and you're there soon..

Comment: Right, i'm following you somehow. Well I understand where each step is coming from, which is something I guess ;o

Comment: I don't understand what i'm supposed to be doing after that..

Answer (score 0):

You did not substitute correctly in what you want to prove. It should be take $(k+1)=100-2(k+1)$.

Your proof should then start take(k+1)=take(k)-2 and plug in your assumption for take(k)

Answer (score 0):

(I'm going to say the same thing over and over again in what I hope are slightly different ways. So see if you can understand any of them, you don't need to understand all of them.)

Induction is a domino chain. The base case is when you tip the first domino. The inductive step is when you set up the dominos, you want the *next* domino to be close enough to the *previous* one, so that when the "previous" one falls, the "next" one will too.

Written with symbols, if $S(n)$ is a sentence with one variable $n$, (i.e. in your example you have $S(n)=$ "take$(n)$ is equal to take$(n-1)$ minus $2$.") then to prove $S(n)$ is true for all $n$, you need

- $S(0)$ to be true
- $S(k+1)$ to be true *under the assumption* that $S(k)$ is known to be true.

The second point is sticky. You are not proving that $S(k)$ is true. You *assume* it is true. What you are proving is that $S(k+1)$ is also true.

When I was learning induction, this always felt like a very stupid thing to do. I thought: well, if you know that $S(k)$ is true for all $k$ then you obviously already know it's true for $k+1$. And in fact, this is true. But this is not what induction is, because in induction you are never given that $S(k)$ is true for *every* $k$. Rather, you only ever know that $S(n)$ is true for a single value of $n$: we *name* that value $k$.

This is why you seemingly randomly change from $n$ to $k$. I always thought this was stupid too, but this is the reason. As a computer scientist this should probably make more sense to you than it did to me: we want to think of $n$ as a variable, but $k$ is supposed to be one specific value of the variable. But of course if $k$ was an actual number like 500 then we couldn't prove very much, so we have to give it a letter name. Now it "looks" like a variable on paper, but never be fooled: it is a value.

Base cases are usually easy. In your particular example, it is easy to see that take$(0)$ is indeed $100-(2\cdot 0)=100$.

Now for the inductive step you play this game:

> I say "Here is a number $k$. I am telling you, $S(k)$ is true."
>
> You say "Why?"
>
> I say "Trust me."
>
> You say "Why?"

We do this for a while until you finally agree to trust me. Maybe I stole the knowledge from the French government, or something, I don't know.

> Then I say "Tell me, is $S(k+1)$ also true?"
>
> You think for a while. Maybe you ask "Is $S(k-1)$ true?"
>
> I say "Sorry, I don't know."
>
> Maybe you ask "Is $S(2)$ true?"
>
> I say "Sorry, I only know that $S(k)$ is true. And I guess you already told me that $S(1)$ was true, so I know that too."

Of course, if I actually gave you a number, like 500, and I said $S(500)$ is true, then you could brute force it. But the point is, I might give you any number, and the goal of the inductive proof is to be prepared regardless of which number $k$ I give you.

Okay, so let's turn to your specific example.

> I say "Here is a number $k$. I am telling you, take$(k)$ is $100-2k$"
>
> […]
>
> Then I say "Tell me, is it true that take$(k+1)=100-2(k-1)$ ?".

So you look at what you know about take$(k+1)$. Well, your definition tells you that for *variable* $n$ you have
$$\text{take}(n)= \text{ take}(n-1)-2.$$
Since $n$ is truly a variable, you can replace it with $k+1$, which is a value. Then you have
$$\text{take}(k+1)= \text{ take}(k+1-1)-2 = \text{ take}(k)-2.$$

This is good news! Why? Because I *already told you* what take$(k)$ is. That was the whole point of using $k$ instead of some other value.

Now, you can finish from here. You want to know take$(k+1)$. You have a relation between take$(k+1)$ and take$(k)$, and you have take$(k)$. Combine these thigns you have for great victory.

---

Final thoughts: Induction problems often to feature odd algebra, which leads some people to think they are bad at induction, when really they just have weak algebra skills. As a loose test, if you understood everything up to your specific example without difficulty, then your problem was probably not induction, it was algebra.